# Create Schema using EF Core failing for npgsql

Tags: npgsql

I’m trying to create a schema using context.

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(“CREATE SCHEMA @p0”, <schemaNameParameter>)
```

It is giving the below error:

> 42601: Syntax error at or near $1

I tried other solutions given for similar question for DML, but they did not work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, may not be very elegant, but works:

```
var con = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
con.Open();
try
{ 
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = $"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS \"<schemaName\">";
        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

PS: Still trying to find a solution which takes a parameter rather than inline value for the schema name. (Note: I'm using regex validation before executing this command to ensure there is no injection attempt)